# dataTables options not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to use this [dataTable javascript library](http://datatables.net/) in my Rails 4 project. I'm using [this rails gem](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) to install the javascript library for convenience.

The problem is that no initialisation options are working. For example:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    pageLength: 50
});
```

This should let there be 50 visible records as default at initialisation, however 10 is still the default. No other options are working ether.

Any hint, or help is appreciated! :)

Comment: try both as string like so : "pageLength": 50, or "pageLength": "50".

Comment: Which version of dataTables are you using? They recently changed. In older Versions it was "iDisplayLength":50

Comment: Ah, dident noticed that. I guess the gem I'm using is using the old version... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're looking for is [iDisplayLength](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options).

From the documentation:

> iDisplayLength - Number of rows to display on a single page when using
>   pagination.

Code:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t7c9F/)**